# What information could be gathered by Javascript within browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm familiar with `Navigator` object, but is there more ways to gather more data about user? OS, extensions, cookie or other in-browser settings - everything i can use to replicate client-side errors.

I know about bunch of analytics services out there, but right now i'm curious, what data could be gathered with vanilla javascript and minimal efforts.

Thank you!

Comment: "*minimal efforts*" - use a library that does it. There are thousands out there.

Comment: Have a look at the research about [browser fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint). There's more than you might believe.

Comment: Can you mention what kind of information you look for? like browser name, location, previous visit, etc

Comment: Usefull article http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/exploring-javascript-device-apis

Answer (score 1):

When you will do

```
console.log(navigator);
```

You will see.In which there is also the OS version (`oscpu`) only for Firefox.
These are the properties in the `navigator` object.

```
platform = Win32
appCodeName = Mozilla
appName = Netscape
appVersion = 5.0 (Windows; en-US)
language = en-US
mimeTypes = [object MimeTypeArray]
oscpu = Windows NT 5.1
vendor = Firefox
vendorSub = 1.0.7
product = Gecko
productSub = 20050915
plugins = [object PluginArray]
securityPolicy =
userAgent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7
cookieEnabled = true
javaEnabled = function javaEnabled() { [native code] }
taintEnabled = function taintEnabled() { [native code] }
preference = function preference() { [native code] }
```

**OSCPU**

[image]

Comment: OP already stated "*I'm familiar with Navigator object*", so what is this answer?

Comment: And OP follows with "_is there more ways to gather more data about user?_". So your code is not helpful since he knows `Navigator`.

Answer (score 0):

The main information come from the user agent string for browser version and OS but it is not guaranteed to be truthful and can be easily hacked and some browsers lie about themselves. You can also get information about the screen size and resolution.